# Concatenating SAS datasets but preserving order of one dataset

Tags: sorting, macros, sas, concatenation, sas-macro

I'm looking to add to a macro used as part of a standard process. The macro currently brings together multiple datasets from different product groups as below:

```
%macro test(group=);
data X;
    set
        %if &group = AAA %then %do;
            LIB.AAA1
            LIB.AAA2
            LIB.AAA3
        %end;
        %else %if &group = BBB %then %do;
            LIB.BBB1
            LIB.BBB2
            LIB.BBB3
        %end;
        %else %if &group = CCC %then %do;
            LIB.CCC1
            LIB.CCC2
            LIB.CCC3
        %end;
    ;

    by customer key var1 var2;


    if first.customer then do;
        <logic>
    end;

run;

%mend;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is inserting my own dataset and preserving its order to meet a new requirement. I also need to do this while changing as little of the standard macro above as possible so I don't affect the rest of the data and downstream processes.

In a separate program that is run before this macro, I have sorted my dataset with an extra variable in between `customer` and `key`. If I just sort by the variables above, my dataset is in the wrong order which will give the wrong `first.customer` results from the `test` macro. This extra variable `type` does not exist in any of the other datasets. I could use an existing variable, but unless I can isolate that too, it would affect the order of the other datasets which I don't want to touch.

The code I have so far:

```
%macro test(group=);
data X;
    set
        %if &group = AAA %then %do;
            LIB.AAA1
            LIB.AAA2
            LIB.AAA3
        %end;
        %else %if &group = BBB %then %do;
            LIB.MYDATA
            LIB.BBB1
            LIB.BBB2
            LIB.BBB3
        %end;
        %else %if &group = CCC %then %do;
            LIB.CCC1
            LIB.CCC2
            LIB.CCC3
        %end;
    ;

    %if &group = BBB %then
        %let byvarlist = customer descending type key var1 var2;
    %else
        %let byvarlist = customer key var1 var2;

    by &byvarlist.;


    if first.customer then do;
        <logic>
    end;

run;

%mend;
```

The BY statement does include the new variable I want, but now of course I am getting the following SAS error for each dataset in group `BBB`:

```
ERROR: BY variable type is not on input data set LIB.BBB1.
```

Adding a length statement hasn't made a difference to the error, neither does the order of the list of `BBB` datasets (i.e. having `MYDATA` above `BBB1` etc.). The other idea I had was to specify my dataset only in the `%if ... %then` logic, like `%if &dataset. = LIB.MYDATA %then ...`, but I'm not sure how to go about this and whether it would still work.

Is there any way of getting around this issue, so my dataset can be sorted further without changing the sort of the other datasets?

Comment: Does this section `%if first.customer %then %do; <logic> %end;` work as expected? Your mixing macro and data step logic there so I'm suspecting that's not quite right.

Comment: It is a little hard to read your code since it cannot work as written. `%if first.customor` cannot work.  I assume you meant `if first.customer`. Also `%if group=` cannot work. I assume you meant `%if &group`.  Sorting by `CUSTOMER newvar KEY` will not impact the  FIRST.CUSTOMER logic.  If you are not using the BY variable KEY why not just remove it from the standard macro and only use CUSTOMER as the BY variable?

Comment: If your data set is ordered in the desire you want, but just not an order that SAS understands, you can look into the `NOTSORTED` option on the BY statement. It will create groups as defined but not check that they're necessarily sorted correctly.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your comments. You're correct - I made the errors when typing up the question from memory, so the code itself works. I've edited my question with the correct code - ```if first.customer```, and ```&group = ```. The BY variable KEY does get used (more so by the other datasets) to identify records belonging to the same customer, and isn't something I can remove unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Reeza, I'll play around with the ```NOTSORTED``` option.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test the code, but you can try saving the set dataset into a temporary one, and then use by statement with more variables. Also sort the dataset X with given by variables before using

```
%macro test(group=);
data X_TEMP;
    set
        %if group = AAA %then %do;
            LIB.AAA1
            LIB.AAA2
            LIB.AAA3
        %end;
        %else %if group = BBB %then %do;
            LIB.MYDATA
            LIB.BBB1
            LIB.BBB2
            LIB.BBB3
        %end;
        %else %if group = CCC %then %do;
            LIB.CCC1
            LIB.CCC2
            LIB.CCC3
        %end;
    ;
run;

%let byvarlist = customer descending type key var1 var2;

proc sort data=X_TEMP; by &byvarlist; 
run;

data X;
 set X_TEMP;
    by &byvarlist.;

    %if first.customer %then %do;
        <logic>
    %end;
run;
%mend;
```

Now X_TEMP will have all the variables including type(even though it is empty for other datasets)

Comment: Thanks for this Rhythm, I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.